# What is CustomBuildRule equivalent in C#?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, code-generation, csproj

I'd like to add a code generator for given filetype. I came across [this example](https://code.google.com/p/steelandconcrete/source/browse/src/proto/Proto.rules?r=0eadc04641ed6ea07093b08c9f56c9983ec02682) which uses `CustomBuildRule`. It seems this is only available for C++ projects. Is there an equivalent for C# projects?